# What credentials does this hardware device steal?

Tags: hardware, usb, ethernet

I was reading about this device the author made, however he did not specify WHAT he was able to steal from a locked computer.

What credentials does this steal?

https://room362.com/post/2016/snagging-creds-from-locked-machines/

Answer (score 2):

The article mentions that [Responder](https://github.com/lgandx/Responder) is used, which is a tool for grabbing NTLM hashes from a variety of Windows protocols using LLMNR/NBT-NS/mDNS poisoning.

Basically, it takes advantage of the fact that many background connections are made by Windows, most of which rely on an identification/resolution protocol that has no guarantee you are talking to a legitimate server.

The same can also be done with a $10 Raspberry Pi Zero (or similar). Take a look at [PoisonTap](https://github.com/samyk/poisontap) as well.